# why when I use javascript won't work in this code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I get tired to find the error. I used javascript with Jquery and php to send and receive data with out refresh the browser. all of it in one file. when i click the button nothing happened. this is the content of my file :

```
<?

if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])){
    header('content-type: text/javascript');

    $resut = ($_POST['user'] == 'ahmad') ? true : false;
    $pass = ($_POST['pass'] == '1234') ? true : false;

    $output = array('user' => $resut,'pass'=>$pass);

    echo json_encode($output);

    exit();
}

?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>

        $('#send').on('click',function(){
            var user = $('#user').val();
            var pass = $('#pass').val();

            $.post("<? echo basename(__FILE__); ?>",{user : user, pass : pass}, function(data){
                if(data.user == true && data.pass == true){
                    $('#content').text('hello '+ user + ' you are already loged in');
                } else {
                    $('#content').text('wrong try it again');
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>


    <input type='text' id='user'>
    <input type='password' id='pass'>
    <input type='submit' id='send' value='login'>

    <div id='content'></div>


</body>
```

Comment: try alert("<? echo basename(__FILE__); ?>"); check if this is right file

Comment: Don't forget to close the <html> tag.

Comment: Can you also add a snippet of the file after the PHP has been rendered?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap JavaScript in

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  // The JavaScript or jQuery code goes here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed writing php on first line

That is

```
<?php 
// Your php code
?>
```

Comment: He's using the [shorthand PHP tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag), and it shouldn't be an issue as long as it's enabled in his configuration.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#send').on('click',function(){
                var user = $('#user').val();
                var pass = $('#pass').val();

                $.post("<? echo basename(__FILE__); ?>",{user : user, pass : pass}, function(data){
                    if(data.user == true && data.pass == true){
                        $('#content').text('hello '+ user + ' you are already loged in');
                    } else {
                        $('#content').text('wrong try it again');
                    }
                });
            });
});
```